Classname does not match in Vitest snapshot
We have a Vitest setup for Vite-based React project using MUI.
When we create a snapshot of a component, the class part will have hashed classnames like the following:
<div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root css-wwkw0y-MuiFormControl-root-MuiTextField-root">

But this wwkw0y might change when we add new tests. Now it is the following:
<div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root css-1nrrp2l-MuiFormControl-root-MuiTextField-root">

wwkw0y became 1nrrp2l and the test fails because the snapshot does not match.
The component and the corresponding test has not been changed.
What to do? We use the latest Vite, Vitest, React, MUI packages.

Frankly I just wouldn't write snapshot tests. That's change detection, not actual behaviour testing.

Ok, the solution was (it was one of my coworker's solution really).
In the Vitest config/setup file import expect and add the following:
import { expect /* and other imports */ } from 'vitest';

expect.addSnapshotSerializer({
  test: (val) => typeof val === 'string',
  print: (val) => `"${(val as string).replace(/css-[a-z0-9]*/g, 'css-test')}"`,
});

This will replace the hashed css classes with "css-test". 
